# Replace Carrier Name with "Free Shipping" when shipping price is zero

Tags: shipping-methods, table-rates, free-shipping, ce-1.9.2.2

I'm using `Magento CE 1.9.2.2` and `Table Rates` is my only shipping method.

The rate **€ 5,00** for all orders **below € 99,95** and **€ 0,00** for all orders of **€ 99,95 or more**.

This is what the `Shipping Method` step looks like when someone places an order of **€ 99,95** or more.

[image: Magento Table Rates]

Now I want to dynamically replace the **"Best Way"** carrier name with **"Free Shipping"** when the order is **€ 99,95 or more**.

I've found out that in

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`

the following code

```
<dt>
    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?>
</dt>
```

is responsible for printing the carier name.

I have tried

```
<dt>
    <?php if ($this->getShippingPrice()== 0): ?>
        <?php echo $this->__('Free Shipping') ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</dt>
```

But this doesn't work. This logic always prints "Free Shipping" even if the shipping price NOT 0,00.

What is the best way to build some logic into this?

Answer (score 0):

First copy file from `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php` to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php
```

and replace bellow function from

```
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                    $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
                }
            }
        }

        // Free shipping by qty
        $freeQty = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            $freePackageValue = 0;
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeShipping = is_numeric($child->getFreeShipping()) ? $child->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                            $freeQty += $item->getQty() * ($child->getQty() - $freeShipping);
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeShipping = is_numeric($item->getFreeShipping()) ? $item->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                    $freeQty += $item->getQty() - $freeShipping;
                    $freePackageValue += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
                }
            }
            $oldValue = $request->getPackageValue();
            $request->setPackageValue($oldValue - $freePackageValue);
        }

        if ($freePackageValue) {
            $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $freePackageValue);
        }
        if (!$request->getConditionName()) {
            $conditionName = $this->getConfigData('condition_name');
            $request->setConditionName($conditionName ? $conditionName : $this->_default_condition_name);
        }

        // Package weight and qty free shipping
        $oldWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
        $oldQty = $request->getPackageQty();

        $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight());
        $request->setPackageQty($oldQty - $freeQty);

        $result = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $rate = $this->getRate($request);

        $request->setPackageWeight($oldWeight);
        $request->setPackageQty($oldQty);

        if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
            $method = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('bestway');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || ($request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty)) {
                $shippingPrice = 0;
            } else {
                $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']);
            }

            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($rate['cost']);

            $result->append($method);
        } elseif (empty($rate) && $request->getFreeShipping() === true) {
            /**
             * was applied promotion rule for whole cart
             * other shipping methods could be switched off at all
             * we must show table rate method with 0$ price, if grand_total more, than min table condition_value
             * free setPackageWeight() has already was taken into account
             */
            $request->setPackageValue($freePackageValue);
            $request->setPackageQty($freeQty);
            $rate = $this->getRate($request);
            if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
                $method = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

                $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
                $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

                $method->setMethod('bestway');
                $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

                $method->setPrice(0);
                $method->setCost(0);

                $result->append($method);
            }
        } else {
            $error = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
            $error->setCarrier('tablerate');
            $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));
            $result->append($error);
        }

        return $result;
    }

**To**

public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
            }
        }
    }

    // Free shipping by qty
    $freeQty = 0;
    if ($request->getAllItems()) {
        $freePackageValue = 0;
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $freeShipping = is_numeric($child->getFreeShipping()) ? $child->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                        $freeQty += $item->getQty() * ($child->getQty() - $freeShipping);
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                $freeShipping = is_numeric($item->getFreeShipping()) ? $item->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                $freeQty += $item->getQty() - $freeShipping;
                $freePackageValue += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
            }
        }
        $oldValue = $request->getPackageValue();
        $request->setPackageValue($oldValue - $freePackageValue);
    }

    if ($freePackageValue) {
        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $freePackageValue);
    }
    if (!$request->getConditionName()) {
        $conditionName = $this->getConfigData('condition_name');
        $request->setConditionName($conditionName ? $conditionName : $this->_default_condition_name);
    }

    // Package weight and qty free shipping
    $oldWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
    $oldQty = $request->getPackageQty();

    $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight());
    $request->setPackageQty($oldQty - $freeQty);

    $result = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    $rate = $this->getRate($request);

    $request->setPackageWeight($oldWeight);
    $request->setPackageQty($oldQty);

    if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
        $method = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('bestway');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || ($request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty)) {
            $shippingPrice = 0;
        } else {
            $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']);
        }

        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($rate['cost']);

        $result->append($method);
    } elseif (empty($rate) && $request->getFreeShipping() === true) {
        /**
         * was applied promotion rule for whole cart
         * other shipping methods could be switched off at all
         * we must show table rate method with 0$ price, if grand_total more, than min table condition_value
         * free setPackageWeight() has already was taken into account
         */
        $request->setPackageValue($freePackageValue);
        $request->setPackageQty($freeQty);
        $rate = $this->getRate($request);
        if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
            $method = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
            $method->setCarrierTitle('Free Shipping');

            $method->setMethod('bestway');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            $method->setPrice(0);
            $method->setCost(0);

            $result->append($method);
        }
    } else {
        $error = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
        $error->setCarrier('tablerate');
        $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));
        $result->append($error);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**To**

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
            }
        }
    }

    // Free shipping by qty
    $freeQty = 0;
    if ($request->getAllItems()) {
        $freePackageValue = 0;
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $freeShipping = is_numeric($child->getFreeShipping()) ? $child->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                        $freeQty += $item->getQty() * ($child->getQty() - $freeShipping);
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping()) {
                $freeShipping = is_numeric($item->getFreeShipping()) ? $item->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                $freeQty += $item->getQty() - $freeShipping;
                $freePackageValue += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
            }
        }
        $oldValue = $request->getPackageValue();
        $request->setPackageValue($oldValue - $freePackageValue);
    }

    if ($freePackageValue) {
        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $freePackageValue);
    }
    if (!$request->getConditionName()) {
        $conditionName = $this->getConfigData('condition_name');
        $request->setConditionName($conditionName ? $conditionName : $this->_default_condition_name);
    }

    // Package weight and qty free shipping
    $oldWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
    $oldQty = $request->getPackageQty();

    $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight());
    $request->setPackageQty($oldQty - $freeQty);

    $result = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    $rate = $this->getRate($request);

    $request->setPackageWeight($oldWeight);
    $request->setPackageQty($oldQty);

    if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
        $method = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('bestway');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || ($request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty)) {
            $shippingPrice = 0;
        } else {
            $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']);
        }

        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($rate['cost']);

        $result->append($method);
    } elseif (empty($rate) && $request->getFreeShipping() === true) {
        /**
         * was applied promotion rule for whole cart
         * other shipping methods could be switched off at all
         * we must show table rate method with 0$ price, if grand_total more, than min table condition_value
         * free setPackageWeight() has already was taken into account
         */
        $request->setPackageValue($freePackageValue);
        $request->setPackageQty($freeQty);
        $rate = $this->getRate($request);
        if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
            $method = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('tablerate');
            $method->setCarrierTitle('Free Shipping');

            $method->setMethod('bestway');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            $method->setPrice(0);
            $method->setCost(0);

            $result->append($method);
        }
    } else {
        $error = $this->_getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
        $error->setCarrier('tablerate');
        $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));
        $result->append($error);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I have added Free Shipping label at line no.184 like this `$method->setCarrierTitle('Free Shipping');`

Comment: I have just tried this but **Free Shipping** does not appear at all. Have you tested this yourself? Thanks!